# Create a Clustering layer for Markers using Angular openlayers directives (ol3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, openlayers-3

I am using Angular Openlayers directive from https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive to make a simple map application. I am trying to create a cluster layer using the ol-layer directive that cluster markers created using ol-marker with ng-repeat:

```
<body ng-app="theApp" ng-Controller="appController as appCtrl">
...
<ol-layer ol-layer-properties="appCtrl.clusterProp"></ol-layer>
<ol-marker ng-repeat="marker in appCtrl.markers"></ol-marker>
...
```

Inside the controller js:

```
var vm = this;
...
vm.clusterProp = {
clustering: true,
clusteringDistance: 40,
source: {
    type: 'Vector'//Does not work
    //What else to put here?
}
};
```

The problem is there is no direct way to pass the  vector layer into the clusterProp object, which is different from the layer-clustering example as seen in http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/059-layer-clustering.html.

The clustering feature is very important for my application but so is the HTML popup feature of ol-marker. I do not want to give up using this angular openlayers directive library if possible.

Has anyone successfully combined ol-marker with a cluster ol-layer?

Comment: I didn't get to use clustering yet (I'll probably need it soon), but I'm very interested in the framed cloud popup integration. If by any chance you implemented something like that and want to exchange figures, please get in touch.